# Первичный ключ в таблице

Tags: sql, sql-server

Повышает ли наличие первичного ключа производительность работы с таблицей, если он не участвует в условии отбора?

Если не ошибаюсь, то наличие первичного ключа задает способ хранения строк.

Если первичного ключа нет, то все хранится в куче. Так же есть некоторые особенности в использовании некластиризированных индексов на куче и без кучи.

Comment: С чего бы ему повышать скорость если ваш запрос без индексов пойдет полным перебором таблицы. и кстати полное сканирование таблицы лежащей "кучей" должно быть быстрее чем такое же чтение кластеризованной таблицы, просто потому, что она занимает меньше места

Comment: @Mike, а если будет поиск по некластеризованному индексу в кластеризованной таблице, то первичный ключ какой-нибудь положительный эффект даст?

Comment: Наличие кластаризованного индекса замедляет работу всех остальных индексов. Потому, что в этом случае остальные индексы содержат не RID записи (по которому чисто расчетно получается ее физический адрес на диске), а значение кластерного ключа. Для поиска записи в кластаризованной таблице по другому индексу сначала надо пройти несколько страниц этого индекса, а потом еще несколько страниц кластеризованного индекса что бы добраться до данных

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/188704/

Comment: Первичный ключ служит в качестве уникального идентификатора записи внутри базы данных. Обычно по совместительству является и идентификатором сущности, состояние которой в записи хранится.  Говоря о первичном ключе, в последнюю очередь подразумевают способ хранения, если вообще эти два понятия как-то связаны.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сам по себе первичный ключ служит для однозначной идентификации строк в таблице, а также для ссылок на строки данной таблицы из других таблиц.

Другое дело, что в SqlServer первичный ключ по умолчанию является *кластерным индексом*. То есть в определении таблицы

```sql
create table TableName (ID int primary key, ... );
```

`primary key` эквивалентно `primary key clustered`. При желании, однако, вполне можно сделать первичный ключ и *некластерным индексом*, указав `primary key nonclustered`.

> Если не ошибаюсь, то наличие первичного ключа задает способ хранения
>   строк.
>   Если первичного ключа нет, то все хранится в куче.

Правильнее будет сформулировать - *наличие или отсутствие кластерного индекса* (не обязательно, чтобы он был первичным ключом).

Если на таблице нет кластерного индекса, то данные таблицы хранятся в куче без какого либо определённого порядка.

Если же на таблице есть кластерный индекс, то в нём и содержатся данные таблицы. Кластерный индекс представляет собой "B+"-дерево, в страницах которого лежат ключи в логически упорядоченном виде. В дополнение к ключам в страницах верхних уровней лежат ссылки на страницы следующего уровня, а в страницах нижнего уровня ("листьях") - данные неключевых столбцов.

---

> Повышает ли наличие первичного ключа производительность работы с
>   таблицей, если он не участвует в условии отбора?

Может повышать.

Сканирование кластерного первичного ключа (вообще кластерного индекса) может быть более производительным по сравнению со сканированием кучи, т.к. в кластерном индексе, в отличие от кучи, при изменении данных не создаются переадресованные записи (т.н. *forwarded records*).

Переадресованная запись - это такая запись, которая, увеличившись в размере при обновлении, уже не может помещаться на той странице данных, где она располагалась. В этом случае запись перемещается на другую страницу данных, а на её месте остаётся указатель. Из-за таких указателей увеличивается число чтений, при доступе к данным.

Пример.

Создадим две почти одинаковых таблицы. Одну с некластерным первичным ключом:

```
create table Heap
(
    ID int,
    Name varchar(50),
    Comments varchar(1000),
    constraint PK_Heap primary key nonclustered (ID)
);
```

Другую, с такими же столбцами, но с кластерным первичным ключом:

```
create table Cluster
(
    ID int,
    Name varchar(50),
    Comments varchar(1000),
    constraint PK_Cluster primary key clustered (ID)
);
```

Добавим в таблицы данных:

```
;with nums as (
    select N = row_number() over (order by @@spid)
    from sys.all_columns a cross join sys.all_columns b
)
insert into Cluster (ID, Name, Comments)
select top (10000)
    N, 'Name ' + cast((N - 1) % 1000 + 1 as varchar(10)), 'Comments'
from nums
order by N;

insert into Heap (ID, Name, Comments)
select ID, Name, Comments from Cluster;
```

Включив `statistics io`, выполним одинаковый запрос к каждой из таблиц - такой, чтобы он вызывал их полное сканирование:

```sql
set statistics io on;
declare @cnt int;
select @cnt = count(1) from Heap where Name = 'Name 15';
select @cnt = count(1) from Cluster where Name = 'Name 15';
set statistics io off;
```

Статистика показывает, что число чтений пока примерно одинаково:

```
Table 'Heap'. Scan count 1, logical reads 61 ...
Table 'Cluster'. Scan count 1, logical reads 63 ...
```

Изменим данные в таблицах (что вызовет появление переадресованных записей в таблице-куче):

```sql
update Heap set Comments = replicate('More ', 50) + Comments
update Cluster set Comments = replicate('More ', 50) + Comments
```

И повторим запросы с `count` и статистикой к таблицам:

```
Table 'Heap'. Scan count 1, logical reads 9139 ...
Table 'Cluster'. Scan count 1, logical reads 680 ...
```

Как видим, хоть данные одни и те же, и изменялись одинаково, и запросы - одинаковые, однако, число чтений, необходимое для сканировании кучи из-за появившихся переадресованных записей выросло на порядок по сравнению с числом чтений, необходимым для сканирования кластерного индекса.